# How to change color of LocatorPane Dynamic point constrained to LogLogPlot line - when point is above set value?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, locator

In the following `LogLogPlot`, I'd like to have the `Dynamic[pt]` color change from `Purple` to `Blue` - when above the `Purple` horizontal line - and change from `Purple` to `Red` when below the line. So far, `Directive[Purple]` initializes the color:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {-9., -55.2}}, LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
LogLogPlot[1/x^3, {x, 10^-12, 10^8},
Epilog -> {
  {PointSize[Large], Directive[Purple], 
   Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], 1/Exp[First@pt]^3 // Log}]]},
  {Inset[Style["\[LongDash]\[LongDash]\[LongDash]\[LongDash]", Bold, Purple], {-9, 
   26.5}]}
          },
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {520, 400}]
]]
```

[image]

However, attempts at using If[...] logic, or the following Which[...] intervals logic, returns the Error message: "Which is not a graphics directive":

```
Directive[Which[
         Dynamic[pt] == {Interval[{.0001, 10^-12}], 
                         Interval[{10^-9, 10^33}]}, Blue,
         Dynamic[pt] == {Interval[{.0001, .001}], Interval[{10^-11, 10^-9}]},
                         Purple,
         Dynamic[pt] == {Interval[{.001, 10^8}], Interval[{10^-11, 10^-25}]},
                         Red]]
```

Also, perhaps I should post this as a separate question, but it would be really tight if the `Locator` itself were constrained to the `x` axis.

Comment: btw, is the original one laggy for you too, or is it only me?

Comment: Nope, neither the original, or @kglr solution, or now my embellished version have any noticeable lag - running on a 2017 MacBook. That is something on my mind though - since I'm working on a loaded up Demonstration Project wondering how well it will work on other systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You can use the second argument of `Dynamic` to restrict the locator to the horizontal axis, and (2) you can use `Dynamic@Directive[If[First[pt] <= -9, Purple, Red]]` to change the color of the point based on the locator position:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {-9., -55.2}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = {#[[1]], -55.2}) &], 
  LogLogPlot[1/x^3, {x, 10^-12, 10^8}, 
   Epilog -> {{PointSize[Large], 
       Dynamic@Directive[If[First[pt] <= -9, Purple, Red]], 
       Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], 1/Exp[First@pt]^3 // Log}]]}, {Inset[
       Style["\[LongDash]\[LongDash]\[LongDash]\[LongDash]", Bold, 
        Purple], {-9, 26.5}]}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {520, 400}]]]
```

[image]